# Edittext focused in first listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focus

When my activity started, edittext focus is always on last item of the listview. I need to get this:

```
1. Edittext focus is always on the first listview item
2. It shows soft input keyboard automatically
```

Here is my Main code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] items = {"Item1","Item2","Item3",..,"Item30"};

        //showing the list
        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listSelected); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new LVAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //how do I implement the code..?
```

LVAdapter code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_item, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

main xml

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listSelected"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSelect" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </Button>
```

And here is my main_item xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextInput"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Both of main.xml and main_item.xml is using RelativeLayout. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the request focus from EditText in the xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextInput"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

and request it programmatically when the `position == 0`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_item, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    if(position == 0){
        EditText etText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);
        etText.requestFocus();
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: In LVAdapter.java or Main.java?

Comment: @Alca yes, inside `getView` method. I edited the code

Comment: Thank you SaNtoRiaN..  To become my coach. :D

Comment: I have new problem. when I finished input all edittext on that listview: 
1. I hit the button, the apps is force close (I tested it on myphone, Its no problem when I tested it on emulator).
2. I hit finish in the last edittext in listview, but all edittext content is vanish.

Comment: @Alca What did the logcat say when it stopped working?

Comment: I tested it in my phone, I think it looks like a "loses content when scrolling list view" issue.. Am I right?

Comment: @Alca yeah I see, You can test your applications from the IDE on the phone and debug them easily, check this link to see how you can run it on your real device also tell me about the logcat when you're done http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Comment: Yosh! Barakallah @SaNtoRiaN